# water jug problem in family tree representation

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, tree

```py
dict_={(0, 0): [(4, 0), (0, 3)], (4, 0): [(4, 3), (0, 0), (1, 3)], (0, 3): [(4, 3), (0, 0), (3, 0)], (4, 3): [(0, 3), (4, 0)], (1, 3): [(4, 3), (0, 3), (1, 0), (4, 0)], (3, 0): [(4, 0), (3, 3), (0, 0), (0, 3)], (1, 0): [(4, 0), (1, 3), (0, 0), (0, 1)], (3, 3): [(4, 3), (0, 3), (3, 0), (4, 2)], (0, 1): [(4, 1), (0, 3), (0, 0), (1, 0)], (4, 2): [(4, 3), (0, 2), (4, 0), (3, 3)], (4, 1): [(4, 3), (0, 1), (4, 0), (2, 3)], (0, 2): [(4, 2), (0, 3), (0, 0), (2, 0)]}
```

This is the dictionary. I want to build a family tree like structure 
something like this:
[image]

I want to do it in python, I don't have an idea where to start.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a tree from a given dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53904239/create-a-tree-from-a-given-dictionary)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems -- not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.  "I don't know where to start" is far too open-ended to be a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.  Best of all, each tutorial will teach you a collection of related techniques, rather than merely solving the immediate problem.